# fill and submit a reactjs form with a script

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I'm tryng to compare some differents frameworks (angularjs, flux+reactjs and emberjs) doing a minimal todo list application.

You can find my code here:

https://github.com/jurgob/todo_test
(in the flux directory you can find the implementation)

I would like to programmatically fill and send the form to add an item to my todo list.

this code works for angular and emberjs:

> $('.addItemText').val('test');  $('.addItemText').change(); 
>   $('.addItemBtn').click();

but not for reactjs.

I've also tried with sendkeys jquery plugin (https://github.com/dwachss/bililiteRange/blob/master/jquery.sendkeys.js) without any success.

here is my flux implementation:
https://github.com/jurgob/todo_test/blob/master/flux/main.js

as additional note: I've build a casperjs script to performe them from an headlerss browser, and using casper.sendKeys function it works for all the framework (you can find the code here https://github.com/jurgob/todo_test/blob/master/tests/maintest.js )

Comment: So you are saying that this _does_ work with casper? These tests sound like they should live at the casper/phantom/selenium level, so personally I would forget trying to test this with jQuery at the unit level, especially since React uses it's own event system. If you could post an isolated example of this failing that would be helpful, a link to a repo is too much work for most people (myself included)

Answer (score 0):

That code should work for react, however you can ditch jQuery in this example and use refs. More information about refs can be found here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

In reality though you shouldn't be setting properties and triggering events on your own, use state to set properties, and you can submit a form request via XHR rather than filling out a form and simulating a click.

I also had a brief look at your code and noticed you were manipulating props directly, this is an anti-pattern, if you need to keep data in sync between different components consider either passing the components back upstream, creating a global eventemitter, or using a pattern like flux: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/05/06/flux.html

Comment: Thanks for your hints, using Flux will be my next step.
For the form submit, if is it possible, I would like to have the same code to fill all my todo-lists.